# How to fix 'Updated field become undefined' issue in MongoDb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently writing a mongoDB query to update set of queries in the db, The requirement is to fetch the db entries that has **mediaOrigin = 'Kaltura'** and the **mediaType= 'YOUTUBE'**, then update the entries as **mediaOrigin= 'AWS'** and the **mediaUrl.dataUrl** and **mediaUrl.downloadUrl** with the value of **mediaUrl.originalUrl**. So I have completed a script to update the relevent queries but the value that the **mediaUrl.dataUrl** and **mediaUrl.downloadUrl** taking is undefined. So how can I solve that, I need to fill that two fields with the value of **mediaUrl.originalUrl**.

Here is the query I have written,

```
try {
db.getCollection('media').find({mediaOrigin: { $eq: 'KALTURA' }, mediaType: {$eq: 'YOUTUBE' }, delete: false
                    
    })
    .forEach(function(media) {
        var youtubeUrl = media.mediaUrl.originalUrl;
                    
        var Url = youtubeUrl;
        
        db.getCollection('media').update(
                            
            {
                _id: media._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    'mediaUrl.downloadUrl': Url,
                                            'mediaUrl.dataUrl': Url,
                                             mediaOrigin: 'AWS'
                }
                                    
            }
        );
    });} catch (e) {
print(e);}
```

So how can I solve that.

Here I have attached the example entry in the db that I need to update.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching `.forEach` end of the `.find()` method get results from your collection.

You have to wait to get results before sending the result into foreach.

So use it like this:

```
const medias = await db.getCollection('media').find({
   mediaOrigin: { $eq: 'KALTURA' },
   mediaType: {$eq: 'YOUTUBE' },
   delete: false 
}).toArray();

medias.forEach(async(media) => {
           var youtubeUrl = media.mediaUrl.originalUrl;
                    
        var Url = youtubeUrl;
        
        await db.getCollection('media').update(
                            
            {
                _id: media._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    'mediaUrl.downloadUrl': Url,
                                            'mediaUrl.dataUrl': Url,
                                             mediaOrigin: 'AWS'
                }
                                    
            }
        );
});
```